# AngularJs Front End and MySQL backend on WAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, wamp

Hi I am creating document control app, where in its simplest form, a database stores the files as blobs. The database also contains a list of users. The user connects through a web-portal and is validated against the users table in the database through a back-end script.

I am using the following: - AngularJs front-end - php as server side code (eg running SQL statements and userauthentication) - mysql as DB - WAMP server

My issue is putting everything together, which I have very little experiencing in and much confusion. I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it correct to store all my front-end angularjs code into the WAMP /www folder? Or should I be running a separate server such as node that connects to the WAMP mysql server?
2. How do I protect access to server-side scripts such as userauth.php in WAMP? Currently this is placed in the www which is accessable through the localhost url.

Appreciate any feedback, this really can get confusing!

Comment: 1) It is completely fine to put all your angularjs code in `/www`
2) why you want to protect `userauth.php`. you will need it to make a http call from client framework (`angularjs` in your case).

Comment: If you are already committed to a php mysql by way of some CMS ect,  you are best to stick with it, there is nothing stopping you from storing data in mysql with PHP server-side code.  If you are able to use other tools, a more ideal situation for a javascript project, node / mongoDB would be a great file storage option,  but I wouldn't do both.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. In regards yiiframe, the reason I want to protect the userauth.php is because I am making a call from clientframework to authenticate the password. If theoretically this accessable by the public in /www isn't that a security issue?.....I am probably missing something here, appreciate comments.